# std::rethrow(std::exception_ptr) not working

Tags: c++, pointers, exception

After JAVA I had to tackle C ++. The simplest example, but it doesn’t work for me:

```
#include <iostream>

void handle_exceptions(std::exception_ptr e);

   std::exception_ptr e;   

int main()
{


    try {
        throw new std::exception("test");
    }
    catch (...) {
        e = std::current_exception();
        handle_exceptions(e);
    }
} // END: main

void handle_exceptions(std::exception_ptr e)
{

    try {

        if (e) { std::rethrow_exception(e); }

    }
    catch (const std::exception & e) {

        std::cerr << std::endl << e.what();
        std::exit(0);
    }
} // END: handle_exception()
```

The line of std::rethrow generates an unhandled exception:
Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x766A08B2 в ConsoleApplication1.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::exception по адресу памяти 0x00BAF1F0.

Possible std::exception_ptr is not NULL. Wrong memory access, but why?

Comment: Can you please (temporarily) change your language settings in Windows to English, and then rerun the program to get the error output in English? While some here understand Russin (I guess) it's a minority.

Comment: FWIW, `new` is not needed in `throw new std::exception("test");`.  You can just use `throw std::exception("test");`.  `new` should not really be used anymore in C++.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception

I don't see any constructor taking `char*` or similiar

Comment: @NathanOliver - But that would change the outcome ;)

Comment: You're throwing an `exception*` but catching a `const exception&`, which will not work. (Also, you have a local variable `e` that shadows a parameter `e`, and both of them shadow a global variable `e`. This is very confusing.)

Comment: Won't compile https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WARpXp

Comment: Google Translate: "An unhandled exception occurred at address 0x766A08B2 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::exception at memory address 0x00BAF1F0."

Comment: Java idioms and semantics are not the same as C++ idioms and semantics.  You may have to unlearn some Java and learn how C++ does things.  There is a selection of [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
throw new std::exception("test");
```

to

```
throw std::exception("test");
```

By the way, std::exception("test") with "test" passed as an argument doesnt compile in my case with g++.